# How does the square end?

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, abstract-algebra

In base-10, all perfect squares end in \$0\$, \$1\$, \$4\$, \$5\$, \$6\$, or \$9\$.

In base-16, all perfect squares end in \$0\$, \$1\$, \$4\$, or \$9\$.

Nilknarf describes why this is and how to work this out very well in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2372342/467325) answer, but I'll also give a brief description here:

When squaring a base-10 number, \$N\$, the "ones" digit is not affected by what's in the "tens" digit, or the "hundreds" digit, and so on. Only the "ones" digit in \$N\$ affects the "ones" digit in \$N^2\$, so an easy (but maybe not golfiest) way to find all possible last digits for \$N^2\$ is to find \$n^2 \mod 10\$ for all \$0 \le n < 10\$. Each result is a possible last digit. For base-\$m\$, you could find \$n^2 \mod m\$ for all \$0 \le n < m\$.

Write a program which, when given the input \$N\$, outputs all possible last digits for a perfect square in base-\$N\$ (without duplicates). You may assume \$N\$ is greater than \$0\$, and that \$N\$ is small enough that \$N^2\$ won't overflow (If you can test all the way up to \$N^2\$, I'll give you a finite amount of brownie points, but know that the exchange rate of brownie points to real points is infinity to one).

Tests:

```
 Input -> Output
 1     -> 0
 2     -> 0,1
 10    -> 0,1,5,6,4,9
 16    -> 0,1,4,9
 31    -> 0,1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10,14,16,18,19,20,25,28
 120   -> 0,1,4,9,16,24,25,36,40,49,60,64,76,81,84,96,100,105
```

this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so standard rules apply!

(If you find this too easy, or you want a more in-depth question on the topic, consider this question: [Minimal cover of bases for quadratic residue testing of squareness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35664/minimal-cover-of-bases-for-quadratic-residue-testing-of-squareness)).

Comment: Does the output array need to be sorted?

Comment: @Shaggy Nope! Mego, Duplication is not allowed. Theoretically, N could be enormous, so duplicates would make the output pretty unreadable. I'll adit the question

Comment: Is outputting a set acceptable?

Comment: @totallyhuman Why wouldn't it be valid? Sets are unordered collections and *it must not be sorted*, so...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Table_of_quadratic_residues for a table of testcases from 0 to 75.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
R²%³Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o0CbVQ5sD////b2wIAA)

#### Explanation

```
R²%³Q   Main link, argument: n

R       Range from 1 to n
 ²      Square each
  %³    Mod each by n
    Q   Deduplicate
```

Answer (score 22):

## Google Sheets, <s>52</s> <s>51</s> 47 bytes

```
=ArrayFormula(Join(",",Unique(Mod(Row(A:A)^2,A1
```

<sub><sup>Saved 4 bytes thanks to Taylor Scott</sup></sub>

Sheets will automatically add 4 closing parentheses to the end of the formula.

It doesn't return the results in ascending order but it does return the correct results.

[image: Results]

Comment: Holy cow, man that is fricken killer! Who would’ve thought?  +1

Comment: This is definitely my favorite answer so far.

Comment: @LordFarquaad I am surprised and pleased this was so well received. I've been trying to golf more in Sheets and Excel even though - and partially because - they have such limited ranges. It's led to a lot of array formulas.

Comment: You should be able to drop the terminating `)`s for -4 bytes

Comment: @TaylorScott Thanks! I saw that trick somewhere recently - probably on one of your answers - and need to remember to start using it.

Answer (score 8):

## [Swift](https://www.swift.org), <s>47 35</s> 32* bytes

* *-3 thanks to @Alexander.*

*Possibly the first time in history Swift <s>ties</s> beats Python?*

```swift
{m in Set((0..<m).map{$0*$0%m})}
```

**[Try it online!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5979f5c2e2406b7625f9fe3f)**

---

## Explanation

- `(0..<m).map{}` - Iterates through the range `[0...m)` and map the following results:
- `$0*$0%m` - The square of each integer modulo the base `m`.
- `Set(...)` - Removes the duplicates.
- `m in` - Assigns the base to a variable `m`

Comment: Username checks out... wait a second.

Comment: More like it beats Python. That is _impressive_! I thought I would never see the day that would happen.

Comment: @CalebKleveter Thanks! I'm glad you found it impressive :)

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
Lns%ê
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fJ69Y9fCq//8NjQwA) or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVln53yevWPXwqv86/w25jLgMDbgMzbiMDbkMjQwA)

```
L     # Range 1 .. input
 n    # Square each
  s%  # Mod by input
    ê # Uniquify (also sorts as a bonus)
```

Comment: How does `s` work here? Is the input repeated?

Comment: @LuisMendo `s` is `pop a,b; push b,a`. When a command tries to pop something from the stack and there isn't anything left the next input is used. If there isn't any more input the last input is used ([here is an example](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fBwT@/zfkMuIyBgA)). In this case I could have used `¹` which pushes the first input, but `s` works better for the test suite.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have more info regarding the criterion for which input gets reused? (if there have been say three inputs and you try to pop two values from an empty stack)?

Comment: @LuisMendo Input is used in order until it runs out, then it continues to use the last element. You could imagine it like the stack was padded with each input in order and an infinite number of the last element.

Comment: @LuisMendo `Ln¹%ê` is equivalent here. `s`.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 6 bytes

```apl
∪⊢|⍳×⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHHasedS2qedS7@fB0IAEUVDA04AISZiACiI0NAQ)

Explanation:

```apl
∪⊢|⍳×⍳
   ⍳×⍳    ⍝ square every number in range from 1 to ⍵
 ⊢|       ⍝ modulo ⍵
∪         ⍝ unique elements
```

Comment: `2*⍨⍳ → ⍳×⍳` for -1 byte.

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
Ç²%UÃâ
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=x7IlVcPi&input=MTIw)

1 byte saved thanks to [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613/oliver)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`.

```
Ç   Ã
```

Create an array of integers from `0` to `U-1`, inclusive and pass each though a function.

```
²
```

Square.

```
%U
```

Modulo `U`.

```
â
```

Get all unique elements in the array and implicitly output the result.

Comment: I don't think the range needs to be inclusive. `Ç²%UÃâ` seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
{%RQ*R
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%7B%25RQ%2aR&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A10%0A16%0A31%0A120)

#### How it works

```
{%RQ*RdQ    implicit variables
       Q    autoinitialized to eval(input())
    *R      over [0, …, Q-1], map d ↦ d times
      d         d
 %R         map d ↦ d modulo
   Q            Q
{           deduplicate
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>40</s> <s>39</s> 37 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder. -2 bytes thanks to Business Cat.*

```python
lambda m:[*{n*n%m for n in range(m)}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYuxCoAgFEV3v@IugYZDFjQEfUk1GGUJ@QpziejbzTpwhwP3HFdYd6qiafu4aTdOGq7p8ptyyhzM7kGwBK9pmbkTzxDDfIYTLTolUUqoIq2WqJKqshgY@yL7Rf@zYUgc3lLghlsh4gs)

Comment: Can't you replace `n**2` with `n*n`?

Comment: Yup, always forget that. >< Thanks!

Comment: Also, just `range(m)` is sufficient

Comment: You can use sets for [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYuxCoAgFEV3v@IugYZDFjQEfUk1GGUJ@QpziejbzTpwhwP3HFdYd6qiafu4aTdOGq65KafMweweBEvwmpaZO/HEMJ/hRItOSZQSqkirJaqkqiwGxr7Gfs3/bBgSh7cUuOFWiPgC)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
>ℕ^₂;?%≜ᶠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/3@5Ry9S4R01N1vaqjzrnPNy24P9/QyOD/1EA)

#### Explanation

```
       ≜ᶠ       Find all numbers satisfying those constraints:
    ;?%           It must be the result of X mod Input where X…
  ^₂              …is a square…
>ℕ                …of an integer in [0, …, Input - 1]
```

Comment: I was about to suggest `{>≜^₂;?%}ᵘ` as an alternative...then I realized there are negative numbers too. >_<

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Once a commit gets pulled to TIO, I can actually reduce this answer to 9 bytes indeed using `≜`.

Comment: OK...how would it work when there are negative numbers too? Would it simply ignore them or something?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer mod can be defined as remainder of division, which would be positive (the quotient takes the sign). EDIT: also, squares are positive.

Comment: @jaxad0127 I don't think that's the case here, since `>` would still account for negative numbers afaik.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer See edit

Comment: @Fatalize You used `≜` so that you can save over `{}`...seems legit.

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 63 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;m=>new int[m].Select((_,n)=>n*n%m).Distinct()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY5BawIxEIXv@RWDICRlDeqhl@3uxapYKggeeihStulYBpIJ7mQrUvztayw99GiP8@Z7j8/JKESOfSfEn7A9ScJQqr@XfSY@lEo534jARn0rSU0iB1@RPmDdEGuTw0XH7oE4Fb@tWfQeXaLIYpfI2JKzqzl3Advm3eMVrWvYQwV9qGrGI@TkNezsFq89rd8KNlWt@Y7NMBj7SJKI88P0WWaWZ6NH@9JSwiyIWlKbne1TzD4DGBSw1xNjTHkbOr0dnYz/wd7/sOqszv0F)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

```js
f=(m,k=m,x={})=>k?f(x[k*k%m]=m,k-1,x):Object.keys(x)
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(m,k=m,x={})=>k?f(x[k*k%m]=m,k-1,x):Object.keys(x)

;[1, 2, 10, 16, 31, 120]
.map(m => console.log(m + ' -> ' + f(m)))
```

---

### Non-recursive version, <s>60</s> 58 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @ThePirateBay*

```js
m=>(a=[...Array(m).keys()]).filter(v=>a.some(n=>n*n%m==v))
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

m=>(a=[...Array(m).keys()]).filter(v=>a.some(n=>n*n%m==v))

;[1, 2, 10, 16, 31, 120]
.map(m => console.log(m + ' -> ' + f(m)))
```

Comment: Non-recursive 58 bytes: `m=>(a=[...Array(m).keys()]).filter(v=>a.some(n=>n*n%m==v))`

Comment: @ThePirateBay Good catch. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 11 bytes

```
;╗r⌠²╜@%⌡M╔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9hY3R1YWxsef//O@KVl3LijKDCsuKVnEAl4oyhTeKVlP//MTA)

Explanation:

```
;╗r⌠²╜@%⌡M╔
;╗           store a copy of m in register 0
  r          range(m)
   ⌠²╜@%⌡M   for n in range:
    ²          n**2
     ╜@%       mod m
          ╔  remove duplicates
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 45 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
f m=nub[n^2`mod`m|n<-[0..m]]
```

-4 bytes from Anders Kaseorg

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRzyezuIQrTSHXNq80KTovzighNz8lIbcmz0Y32kBPLzc29n9uYmaebUFRZl6JSpqCocF/AA)

Comment: Sadly point-free version `f m=nub$map((\`mod\`m).(^2))[0..m]` is just as long, unless there is a sneaky syntax to get rid of extra parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 12 bytes

```
{_,_.*\f%_&}
```

Anonymous block accepting a number and returning a list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/Ol4nXk8rJk01Xq32f13Bf2NDAA)

#### Explanation

```
_,          Copy n and get the range [0 .. n-1]
  _.*       Multiply each element by itself (square each)
     \f%    Mod each by n
        _&  Deduplicate
```

Comment: Nice! I had `{:X{_*X%}%_&}` for 13 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @LuisMendo

```
:UG\u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yrUPab0/39DAwA)

Comment: Thanks! I looked through the doc searching for that function but wasn't able to find it.

Comment: BTW this [interpreter](https://matl.suever.net/#) created by Suever has documentation search, you may find it useful

Answer (score 2):

## AWK, <s>44</s> <s>43</s> 40 bytes

```
{for(;i++<$0;)if(!a[j=i*i%$0]++)print j}
```

I managed to cut off 3 bytes after revisiting this old answer.

Step by step:

```
{
for(;i++<$0;)        For all numbers less of equal to the input...
            
if(!a[j=i*i%$0]++)   Increments the element j of the array a.
                     j is the last digit of each i*i.
                     If the element a[j] is being incremented
                     for the first time (a[j]++ returns 0,
                     so negating it (!a[j]++) returns 1)...

print j              Prints j.
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMM6U1vbRsXAWjMzTUMxMTrLNlMrU1XFIFZbW7OgKDOvRCGr9v9/QwMA)

#### Former answer (43 bytes)

```
{for(;i++<$0;)a[i*i%$0];for(j in a)print j}
```

Edit: Incrementing the `i` variable during the `for` condition saved one more byte.

Step by step:

```
{                        
for(;               # starts the loop with no previous statement.
    i++<$0;)        # loops while _i_ is less than the input ($0).
                    # also increments 1 to the _i_ variable after
                    # it is evaluated.

    a[i*i%$0];      # fiat the _i*i%$0_ element of the _a_ array!
                    # by only stating _array[element]_, the element exists.
                    # i*i%$0 means: i squared (mod $0), i.e., the last digit.

for(j in a)         # for every element _j_ existing in the _a_ array,
    print j         # prints the element _j_
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMM6U1vbRsXAWjMxOlMrU1XFINYaJJylkJmnkKhZUJSZV6KQVfv/v6EBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>32</s> 30 bytes

Simple use of the *easy tip* from OP.

```scala
(0 to n-1).map(x=>x*x%n).toSet
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFBQzcWZkpqmUFxYmliU6pqXopFn5ZlXomkVnFoSDWTE2lb/1zBQKMlXyNM11NTLTSzQqLC1q9CqUM3T1CvJB6r6X8vFVVCUmVeSk6ehZKiga6egpI0wzVBTEyFrhC5rhCxraICh2QBF3gxD3gxZ3hjDcmMU2w2NMC0wAtlQ@x8A)

-2 bytes thanks to @MrXcoder, with priorities (no need for `()` around `*` operation)

Wondering: is this possible to *implicitly* tell the compiler to understand things like `(0 to n-1)map(x=>x*x%n)toSet` (without having to `import scala.language.postfixOps`)?

Comment: `(0 to n-1).map(x=>x*x%n).toSet` for 30 bytes. Exponentiation has higher precedence than modulo.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder ooh~ thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 27 bytes

```matlab
@(n)unique(mod((1:n).^2,n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330EjT7M0L7OwNFUjNz9FQ8PQKk9TL85IJ09T83@ahqEmV5qGEYgwNACTZiDSGCxsaGSg@R8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 30 bytes

```
Union@Table[Mod[i^2,#],{i,#}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvs/NC8zP88hJDEpJzXaNz8lOjPOSEc5Vqc6U0e5Nlbtf0BRZl6JgkOagoOhkcF/AA)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 48 bytes

```js
f=
n=>[...new Set([...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>i*i%n))]
```

```html
<input type=number min=0 oninput=o.textContent=f(+this.value)><pre id=o>
```

43 bytes if returning a `Set` instead of an array is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <del>31</del> 30 bytes

```ruby
->m{(0..m).map{|n|n*n%m}.uniq}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvxfYBvzX9cut1rDQE8vV1MvN7GguiavJk8rTzW3Vq80L7Ow9n@0oY6RjqGBjqGZjrGhjqGRQaxeamJyRnVNbo1CQWlJsYKScnVurZWCcnVBdG5srVLtfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 44 bytes

```hs
f m=[k|k<-[0..m],or[mod(n^2)m==k|n<-[0..m]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xCsIwGAZf5aM4JPRvaSI4mT6BTo4xSkClkv5JaSsuffdoBbfjbrjOT@He9zk/wMaGJewr29Q1O0qj5XQT8aIlGxOW@C/OZfbPCAP2w/EKcWZULYbXfJrHQ8QGU5feYJQlirUUK/2c@F6khFWkSTWkdrRVpHTj8gc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 19 bytes

```perl6
{set (^$_)»²X%$_}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##VZDBbsIwDIbveQoLlZEOU5LQhlYVE9edt8MO09DWBgmplIqEaRPipXbdjRfrHECF5RT//@/PlhuzrXS7swY@dVTkbP0Nd8WmNDBr99Y44G/BIjz@Hn9e@sHi0JI9d8Y6mEG1qo3l5EXFZv3Bx6/lcOyrx9rlzAOfKZezpnqvYXhqytlys730jx6AQ7Cqm51DuJ@br8YUzpQQwp4B0Jigk2bQ2dGTIcrZ3xq7q/wifl1@RoXeXNlRaUxTdRm8whB6l6nRcu34oD9K7CD021yyUUMH4WEvZ4cWJPhHpmCguj9KBlJcK0xQY4wZqfpGPSkTeaMo0hKcYooZShJilBplijJDJVAlqFJiKPGP4TMq9u6EpgiMM9QCdYxTjanElCIEEZQWyR8)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{ # bare block lambda with implicit param ｢$_｣

  set        # turn the following into a Set (shorter than ｢unique｣)

      (
        ^$_  # a Range upto (and excluding) ｢$_｣
      )»²    # square each of them (possibly in parallel)

    X%       # cross modulus the squared values by

      $_     # the input
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 71 bytes

```
> Input
>> [1)
>> L²
>> L%1
>> Each 3 2
>> Each 4 5
>> {6}
>> Output 7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hMvOTiHaUBNE@RzaBKZUDUGUa2JyhoKxghGcbaJgCmJXm9WCKP/SEqBuBfP/QLb5wy27kMQs/xsaGQAA)

The TIO Footer simply sorts the output, remove it to see the unsorted set.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
{?x!*/&=x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxVj9FOwzAMRd/zFUYgBMhd4zRN01bAM098wIS0qkvXaaPd1lR0msa34w4GLC++Prm5savs8DxcPYS3j8NRCJ8dbqb7z11WAcCQz9pVfjeriuU6H/J9vrt/Owo/pRzlG1eVS6BRkBwVxGBAQ3oi5kR+uojOHZABFbOTLCigFBJQrPhWA0mwp7dK5nDpjzg4BaPBEtskKA2JYRWD1aAlpAYMjyREKGrvN10WhmU7d4t2XU06X5QrN5R10SzcpGzfw23vOr9smy6kyMjEhnX7Ecxb1wW+dkG37YudC1wzDxUZG+nr7yIEvDSb3kPwBK+9ZyV4xvEwkILXOWskMS7z22GMBjWmYtzmj55IRP+IYhZjghZTJAYaySBZpBSVRBWjspyh5EXG6FF6vI34F4k6RSPRaEwMWkLLFg6R7JbxF36gcJU=)

- `&=x` generate a list containing `(0..x; 0..x)`
- `*/` multiply the two items of the list together
- `x!` mod the result by `x`
- `?` (implicitly) return the distinct last digits

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
ɾ²$%U
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvsKyJCVVIiwiIiwiMTIwIl0=)

```
ɾ     # 1...n
 ²    # Each squared
   %  # Modulo...
  $   # input
    U # Uniquify the result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 5 bytes

```
`$.,$%^$~@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWqxJU9HRUVONU6hwgAlDxBRsMuYy4DA24DM24jA25DI0MIOIA)

```
`$ Deduplicate
.   map
,    range
$     input
%    mod
^     power
$      it
~      2
@     input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
L²ŒU
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPUwlQzIlQjIlQzUlOTJVJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MTIwJmZsYWdzPQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
L²ŒU  # Implicit input
L     # Push [0..input)
 ²    # Square each value
  Œ   # Mod by input
   U  # Uniquify
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 70 bytes

```
.+
$*

;$`¶$`
1(?=.*;(.*))|;1*
$1
(1+)(?=((.*¶)+\1)?$)

D`1*¶
^|1+
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYuLy1ol4dA2lQQuQw17Wz0taw09LU3NGmtDLS4VQy4NQ21NoLAGUPDQNk3tGENNexVNLi6XBEMgnyuuxhBohJ7a//@GBgA) Warning: Slow for large inputs. Slightly faster 72-byte version:

```
.+
$*

$'¶$';
1(?=.*;(.*))|;1*
$1
+s`^((1+)¶.*)\2
$1
^1+

D`1*¶
^|1+
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYuLS0X90DYVdWsuQw17Wz0taw09LU3NGmtDLS4VQy7t4oQ4DQ1Dbc1D24DCMUYgsThDbS4ulwRDrUPbuOJqgBwVPbX//40NAQ)

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 40 bytes

```
#(set(map(fn[x](mod(* x x)%))(range %)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

```
VQ aY.^N2Q){Y
```

[Try online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQ+aY.%5EN2Q%29%7BY&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A10%0A16%0A31%0A120&debug=0)

Lame attempt at explaining:

```
VQ               for N in [0 .. input-1]
                   blank space to supress implicit print inside the loop
     .^N2Q         N ^ 2 % input
   aY              append that to Y, which is initially an empty list
          )      end for
           {Y    deduplicate and implicit print
```

To sort the output, insert an `S` on any side of the `{`

I think there should be a shorter way...

Comment: Yeah, the functional style of Pyth tends to be [much more concise](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136315/39242). `map` is your friend!

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

```python
t=int(input())
print list(set([(i*i)%t for i in range(t)]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcchDoAwDAVQzylqSFrk0JyEIBADfkK6ZfsITl947tWXV/EUwQVOhdeHajbU9ldudGrP1FUxwUbKUZpA4NJ2P7PSNrOIOX0)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 35 bytes

```powershell
0..($n="$args")|%{$_*$_%$n}|sort -u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30BPT0Mlz1ZJJbEovVhJs0a1WiVeSyVeVSWvtqY4v6hEQbf0////hkYGAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
unique((1:(n<-scan()))^2%%n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzQvs7A0VUPD0Eojz0a3ODkxT0NTUzPOSFU1T/O/sdF/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), <s>138</s> 131 bytes

**Code**

```
[] swap dup >r ( 2 ^ r@ n:mod a:push ) 1 rot loop rdrop ' n:cmp a:sort ' n:cmp >r -1 a:@ swap ( tuck r@ w:exec ) a:filter rdrop nip
```

**Explanation**

`[]` - Create output array

`swap dup >r` - Save input for later use

`( 2 ^ r@ n:mod a:push ) 1 rot loop` - Compute square end

`rdrop` - Clean r-stack

`' n:cmp a:sort` - Sort output array

`' n:cmp >r -1 a:@ swap ( tuck r@ w:exec ) a:filter rdrop nip` - Get rid of consecutive duplicates from array

**SED** (Stack Effect Diagram) is: `a -- a`

**Usage and example**

```
: f [] swap dup >r ( 2 n:^ r@ n:mod a:push ) 1 rot loop rdrop ' n:cmp a:sort ' n:cmp >r -1 a:@ swap ( tuck r@ w:exec ) a:filter rdrop nip ;

ok> 120 f .
[0,1,4,9,16,24,25,36,40,49,60,64,76,81,84,96,100,105]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>86</s> 77 bytes

```java
n->java.util.stream.IntStream.range(1,n+1).map(a->a*a%n).distinct().toArray()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZAxT8MwEIXn@Fd4QXKgsShrIRKgVmJADBkRwxE7wSWxzflStUL97eHUlKVFeLH17vzufbeGDRQhWr82n6PrY0CSa9b0QK7T94iwSwtxVmgGX5MLXq@Ojz96EqGFXl8uhIjDe@dqWXeQknwG58W3yI5iIiC@NsEZ2XNJVYTOt69vErBNuci4NXvyVE12CL61j11I1qj5TM5vrnPdBFxC/fGCxiLLW1mUstolsr0OA@nIftR5NdFoCtMEZSxZ7J231dcAaJfesJpWAR8gWbXN@SxEthenUdmN0/3/m3vk9hj@d0e3TGFbi7PJoZSNvBt9UZ6t7ISWOf3VPNc9RAVFCZdw4XNtXCLHxipnogOaykfOm6GlAb1sNMTY7ZjjALEffwA)

Comment: Check your byte count, and you can save by using `java.util.stream.IntStream` instead of the import.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 53 bytes

```php
for(;$i<$t=$argv[1];)$a[$z=$i++**2%$t]++?:print"$z
";
```

Loop from 0 to the input number, using the `n^2 mod base` formula to mark numbers that have been used. It goes to that position in an array, checking if it's been incremented and outputting it if it hasn't. It then increments it afterwards so duplicate values don't get printed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVMm1USmxVEovSy6INY601VRKjVapsVTK1tbW0jFRVSmK1te2tCooy80qUVKq4lKz/29v9NzQDIgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=uniq -na`, 32 bytes

```perl
say for uniq map$_**2%"@F",0..$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhLb9IoTQvs1AhN7FAJV5Ly0hVycFNScdAT08l/v9/Q4N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNgLRPZnGJlVVoSWaOLUjnf928RAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 25 bytes

```
n->Set([x^2%n|x<-[1..n]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1y44tUQjuiLOSDWvpsJGN9pQTy8vNlbzf2JBQU6lRp6Crp1CQVFmXgmQqQTiKCmkaeRpauooRBvqKBjpKBgaALGZjoIxkGtoZADUCQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 49 bytes

```
N+X:-setof(K,A^(between(0,N,A),K is A^2mod N),X).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcyxCsMgFEbhV3G8kt@iFjpkcw44B9pmCL0tQoxBBR/fOp7hO1dOR/qp0kLvflpnVbimLy1wG@1cG/NJGh5OYhGhCLfZmD7CS6zy1mcVOe6cyeNpYGE0zAN3A2P1W2IM8ZpaDpWPk0YN8gc)

Creates a set of values from `K=(A^2)%N`, where `0<=A<=N`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 7 bytes

```
Đř²⇹%Ụş
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARkA5v9weXT//8SQxZnCsuKHuSXhu6TFn///MTIw)

```
Đ            implicit input (n); Đuplicate on stack
 ř           řangify (push [1,2,...,n])
  ²          square
   ⇹%        modulo n
     Ụş      get Ụnique elements and şort in ascending order; implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `D`, \$ 6 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.94 bytes

```
R2^$ZU
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSi1LsgqWlJWm6FsuCjOJUokIhHKjYgsWGRgYQJgA)

### [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 7 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 5.76 bytes

```
DR2^$ZU
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLXYKM4lSiQiE8qOCCxYZGBhAmAA)

##### Explanation

```python
DR2^$ZU  # Implicit input
DR       # Duplicate and get range(input)
  2^     # Square each number
    $    # Mod by the input
     ZU  # Uniquify
         # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 45 bytes

```javascript
n=>(g=x=>x?g(g[x*x%n]=x-1):Object.keys(g))(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQ0wRbkGRfEcyO0AGijxIbmWhkxDq9vefXd832Pq6nefuyU4lkgEnIyMjAs9RSxYWk0ThMm3f2Uaf7MjAiRCw2xZyCUyEx7KC7FrH8)

### 40 bytes

With output as an array that could contain multiple empty items.

```javascript
n=>(g=x=>x?g(x-1,a[y=x*x%n]=y):a)(a=[n])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQ0wRbZGRfEcwOIn4MSSlCI0PW6e29kysX/xz3q@rSArVEBiIJGdkiiNID24@kly45@nBlBCabHDafU8nXPl45QgA9T4jtBw)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 10 bytes

```
~.@:|2^~i.
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxqk7PwarGKK4uUw8icFNJkys1OSNfQUdP36rOIU1Nz07BUMFIwdBAwdBMwdhQwdDIAKJywQIIDQA)

```
~.@:|2^~i.
        i.  NB. range [0..n)
     2^~    NB. square
  @:        NB. then
~.          NB. uniquify
```